# Keeping footer visible and height 100% in CSS

Tags: html, css, height

I'm trying to create a very simple page that contains a container, a header, a left column and a footer:

```
<containter>
<header />
<content />
<leftBar />
<footer />
</containter>
```

I want to use the 100% of the height, as I can do with the width, but I simply don`t get it work.At his moment I'm using` min-height`, but how could I use the` height:100%` ? What I like is that the footer is always visible, and you scroll the content.

#### Current CSS

```
body
{
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    background-color:#f1f1f1;
}

#container {
   border:solid 2px Black;
   position:absolute;
   left:10%;
   width:80%;
   margin:auto;
}

#header {
  height:20px;
  background: #DDDDDD;
}

#leftBar {
  width: 20%; 
  background: #669966; 
  min-height:600px;
  postion:absolute;
  top:20px;
  bottom:20px;
}

#content {
  float:right;
  background-color: #cdcde6;
  position:absolute;
  left:20%;
  right:0px;
  bottom:20px;
  top:20px;
  padding:5px;
}

#footer {
 position:absolute;
 height:20px;
}
```

Comment: To paste in the code, you need to indent *all* of the lines by 4 spaces, not just the first line - you can do this easily by hilighting the block of code and then clicking the little "101010" button above the entry box (it's to the left of the picture and the right of the quote mark).

Comment: Thanks! I'll remember it for the next time, thanks to the editor too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/**
 * The following allows the usage of height=100% in body tag.
 * Creds to: http://apptools.com/examples/tableheight.php
 */
html,body
{
    margin    : 0;
    padding    : 0;
    height    : 100%;
    border    : none;
}
```

You need to make it so html and body take 100% of the browser viewport.

Answer (score 1):

I´m not sure if this is exactly what you are asking for, but it is a good resource when it comes to css layout http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-multi-column-liquid-layouts. It also has an article explaining how to add it into a container: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/how-to-convert-a-liquid-layout-to-fixed-width

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<style>
  html, body { margin: 0 auto; height: 100%; }
  #container { height: 100%; width: 80%; background: #e0e0e0; margin: 0 auto;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/uyezu

Trick is to expand html,body to 100%

Answer (score 1):

I've actually just fixed a similar problem myself this evening, and the following link provided the perfect solution:

http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this for years, still works great:

**footerStickAlt: A more robust method of positioning a footer**
http://www.themaninblue.com/writing/perspective/2005/08/29/